# wp_head() - list hooked actions with priorities?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, headers, wp-head

I'd like to add something to `wp_head()` but I'm aiming precise location (like after style.css but before rtl.css and before my other custom script). I'm wondering if it's possible to list everything that is attached to `wp_head()` in execution/display order anyhow?

I know that I can pass priority/order parameter to `add_action` but I need to know what number will that be.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_function', 10 );
```

It all starts with `10` but somehow rtl.css seems to be always after style.css. Is it `11` maybe? How do I find that out?

Comment: I found an answer :) For anyone wondering it's here: http://www.presscoders.com/2010/10/closeup-look-at-the-wp_head-action-hook/ - extremely useful piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can practically control order of hooked things by priority, it's not always the right tool for the job.

In case of styles you should be using appropriate [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_style/) function which allows you to easily set up elaborate dependencies which will be automagically processed by WP to produce desired order of styles output.

Unfortunately while there is analogous [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_enqueue_scripts/) for scripts, you cannot cross-depend scripts and styles like your question indicates. However it is common practice to not start JS execution until page has fully downloaded, so in most cases explicit depending on CSS should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually trying to create a `<style>` tag with user CSS. This can't be done with `wp_enqueue_style` unless a new CSS file is created. So, it's an exception :)